# Can I use email addresses as usernames with Subversion?

Tags: email, svn, user-accounts, svnserve

Will subversion accept usernames such as firstname.lastname@domain.com?

We are using svn+ssh with public key authentication as per the official svn guide's [ssh tips and tricks section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks).

Basically, we pass svnserve with the --tunnel-user={username} command, will subversion be OK with that username having @ and . in it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, but it should work. The only tricky place is where you want to include username in SVN URL. Standard URL-escaping rules would require `%40` instead of `@`:

```
svn+ssh:user%40emailhost@svnhost
```

Comment: Would this also apply to TortoiseSVN?